# Vb.net Connection to MySql

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, connection, vb.net-2010, sqlconnection

I'm using vb.net windows form application, in which I have used the connection string as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con1 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\alu\aludb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
End Sub
```

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and created database on the same.
It works fine, But note that I've used G:

If I copy the project to another computer(probably that doesn't have G:) D: or E:, I need to change the connection.

Is there any way to take the path automatically from where my project is actually located?

If so then please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) Property, it will show your application path

```
con1 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" &  
Application.StartupPath & "\alu\aludb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User 
Instance=True")
```

Comment: how to use it in my connection string